# Reordering Newsfeed based on PHP function call

Tags: php, mysql, feed

I am trying to create a feature which essentially amounts to a Facebook style newsfeed. In order to order this newsfeed, I call and get all the information associated with all existing "stories" and orders them based on time.

However, I want to reorder these "stories" based on the outcome of a subsequent PHP call. How would you suggest that I go about this? I am really lost right now, so anything that could get me within the ball park would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP usort might be what you're looking for:

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->somefield == $b->somefield) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->somefield < $b->somefield) ? -1 : 1;
}

$feeds = getFeeds();

usort($feeds, "cmp");

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php